# how to test my local page on Fetch as Googlebot

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

I have written a page and need to test it locally.

How can I see the result of my development site served from my local machine using Google's "Fetch As Google" feature in Webmaster Tools?

Comment: What do you mean by local and what do you mean by "fetch google bot"?

Answer (score 5):

(disclaimer: more of a comment than an answer)

This is an excellent question and there are amazingly little sources on the web for a solution.

**Fetch Google Bot** - http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=158587

> The Fetch as Googlebot tool lets you
>   see a page as Googlebot sees it. This
>   is particularly useful if you're
>   troubleshooting a page's poor
>   performance in search results. For
>   example, if you use rich media files
>   to display content, the page returned
>   by the tool may not contain this
>   content if Google can't crawl it
>   effectively. You can choose to fetch a
>   page as Google's regular web crawler
>   sees it or, if you publish mobile
>   content, as our mobile crawlers do.

I followed the link above and tried out User Agent Switcher but it doesn't accomplish what the asker is looking for.  See this thread: chrispederick.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=788

> You can change the user agent settings
>   to be the same as GoogleBot, for
>   example, but I'm not sure if sites
>   also change their appearance based on
>   the headers the search bot sends.
>   Changing the headers is beyond the
>   scope of the extension, however.

And chrispederick.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=259

Q

> For example if i put googleBot i'd
>   like it to customize that it would be
>   emulate Google's spider.

A

> The User Agent Switcher has always
>   been designed to be a simple,
>   light-weight solution so I'm not
>   planning on adding anything like this.

In short I don't think there is a solution.  This would be a great opportunity for a google app

Comment: Fetch Google Bot doesn't work with sites which were set up locally. The question was how to test a local page :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to see how your site will react to the google web crawler?

For this you could use Firefox with the [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59/) addon.

Comment: i have installed it but cant figure out how to use it
http://chrispederick.com/work/user-agent-switcher/features/test/

Answer (score 1):

In order to test your localhost website with the official Google tools, you can use Ngrok as i described in this post : https://www.aymen-loukil.com/en/blog-en/how-to-test-localhost-website-with-google-seo-tools/

Fetch as Google is not possible to use directly with non verified domain in Google Search Console (Webmaster tools). A trick to view it, is to iframe your Ngrok URL in a another verified domain.
- you should have a website verified in Search console
- Make an iframe that loads your Ngrok URL of your localhost webpage

Answer (score 1):

Ngrok + Fetch as google combination is great, but you will need to go through the verification process each time you launch ngrok on the google tools side.

In my case I just needed to check if server side render was properly done, just went to google Chrome navigator settings and disabled javascript:

Settings >> Advanced >> Content Settings >> Disable >> Javascript Allowed (off)

[image]

It allowed me to check that the page was being 100% rendered in the server side(nextjs server side rendering) and no JavaScript render was being run on the client side.